# How to set a check box to checked inside a table

Tags: jquery

I am having a control which is rendering as html table where I am trying to set a check box to selected based on a value. Here is the code I am trying

```js
var button = $("button")
var defaultValue = "1";
// handle click and add class
button.on("click", () => {
  $('#ctl00_MainContentCPH_ReportViewerCriteria_ReportParm10 tbody > tr').each(function(i, row) {
    $checkedBoxes = $(row).find('input[type=checkbox]')
    $checkedBoxes.each(function(i, checkbox) {
      //alert($(this).attr('name'));
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Set Value</button>
<table id='ctl00_MainContentCPH_ReportViewerCriteria_ReportParm10'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span checkboxvalue="-1" displaytext="All Sports">
          <INPUT id='ctl00_MainContentCPH_ReportViewerCriteria_ReportParm10_0' type='checkbox' name='ctl00$MainContentCPH$ReportViewerCriteria$ReportParm10$0' />
          <LABEL for='ctl00_MainContentCPH_ReportViewerCriteria_ReportParm10_0'>All Sports</LABEL>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <TR>
      <TD><SPAN checkboxvalue="1" displaytext="Cricket">
          <INPUT type='checkbox' name='ctl00$MainContentCPH$ReportViewerCriteria$ReportParm10$1' />
          <LABEL for='ctl00_MainContentCPH_ReportViewerCriteria_ReportParm10_1'>Cricket</LABEL></SPAN></TD>
    </TR>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you see I have a default value as so based on this cricket should be selected when I click the button can some one help me

Comment: Aren't you just missing the check of the checkbox? Like $( elem ).prop( "checked" ) See https://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`prop('checked', true)`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```js
var button = $("button")
var defaultValue = "1";

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", () => {
  var $table = $("#ctl00_MainContentCPH_ReportViewerCriteria_ReportParm10")

  $table.find('[checkboxvalue] :checkbox:checked').prop('checked', false)
  $table.find('[checkboxvalue="' + defaultValue + '"] :checkbox').prop('checked', true)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Set Value</button>
<table id='ctl00_MainContentCPH_ReportViewerCriteria_ReportParm10'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span checkboxvalue="-1" displaytext="All Sports">
          <INPUT id='ctl00_MainContentCPH_ReportViewerCriteria_ReportParm10_0' type='checkbox' name='ctl00$MainContentCPH$ReportViewerCriteria$ReportParm10$0' />
          <LABEL for='ctl00_MainContentCPH_ReportViewerCriteria_ReportParm10_0'>All Sports</LABEL>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <TR>
      <TD>
        <SPAN checkboxvalue="1" displaytext="Cricket">
          <INPUT type='checkbox' name='ctl00$MainContentCPH$ReportViewerCriteria$ReportParm10$1' />
          <LABEL for='ctl00_MainContentCPH_ReportViewerCriteria_ReportParm10_1'>Cricket</LABEL></SPAN>
      </TD>
    </TR>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi how can I clear all selections before checking one

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the checked property to true.

```js
var button = $("button")
var defaultValue = "1";
// handle click and add class
button.on("click", () => {
   $('#ctl00_MainContentCPH_ReportViewerCriteria_ReportParm10 tbody > tr').each(function(i, row) {
       $checkedBoxes = $(row).find('input[type=checkbox]')
       $checkedBoxes.each(function(i, checkbox) {
           $(checkbox)[0].checked = true;
       });
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Set Value</button>
<table id='ctl00_MainContentCPH_ReportViewerCriteria_ReportParm10'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span checkboxvalue="-1" displaytext="All Sports">
          <INPUT id='ctl00_MainContentCPH_ReportViewerCriteria_ReportParm10_0' type='checkbox' name='ctl00$MainContentCPH$ReportViewerCriteria$ReportParm10$0' />
          <LABEL for='ctl00_MainContentCPH_ReportViewerCriteria_ReportParm10_0'>All Sports</LABEL>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <TR>
      <TD><SPAN checkboxvalue="1" displaytext="Cricket">
          <INPUT type='checkbox' name='ctl00$MainContentCPH$ReportViewerCriteria$ReportParm10$1' />
          <LABEL for='ctl00_MainContentCPH_ReportViewerCriteria_ReportParm10_1'>Cricket</LABEL></SPAN></TD>
    </TR>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You are selecting all I need only 1 check box to be selected